# How to access the conditionizr object?

Tags: javascript, touch, browser-detection

I need to know if a user is using a mobile touch device in my JavaScript code to not register any hover eventHandlers. Since I don't want to use userAgent sniffing like:

```
isMobile = function() {
  return /iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry/.test(navigator.userAgent);
};
```

I'd expected conditionizr gives me something like `conditionizr.isTouch`. The solution I came up with is to test for the touch class like this:

```
isMobile = function() {
  return $('#conditionizr').hasClass('touch');
};
```

This works because conditionizr adds the class touch to the html

```
<html id="conditionizr" class=" chrome no-retina no-touch mac">
```

But I guess there is a better way to access the settings right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update on Conditionizr v4 release

The new Conditionizr APIs do exactly what you want above:

```
if (conditionizr.touch) {
    // touch
}
```

... As well as many other brilliant enhancements such as the .on() API:

```
conditionizr.on('chrome', function () {
    // callback for Chrome
});
```

And much more!

http://conditionizr.com

Answer (score 2):

The settings and internal variables are not exposed, but you can simply use the same check conditionizr is using:

```
isMobile = function() {
  return ('ontouchstart' in window)
}
```